# Typescript TS7017: implicitly any for a Pipe in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript1.8

I just started working with Angular 2 and am still having some trouble in using typescript correctly. I made the following custom pipe that helps me iterate over objects:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'mapToIterable' })
export class MapToIterablePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(dict: Object): any {
        var a:any = [];
        for (var key in dict) {
            if (dict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      --->      a.push({ key: key, value: dict[key] });
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

When I compile this however I get a "error TS7017: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type. I don't really understand how I can write my function in such a way that this error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in this line:

```
var a:any = [];
```

You are defining `a` to be of type `any` but are using it as if it were defined as an array `a.push(...)`. You can fix it with either of these options:

```
// explicitly define a as an array of any's
var a: any[] = [];
// allow TypeScript to infer the type as an array
var a = [];
```

Comment: Hmm that didn't do the trick. The error message also refers to line 9, the one where I put an arrow. Your solution keeps giving me: error TS7017: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: Seems to be working fine in the playground, perhaps you have another issue locally (maybe your tsconfig.json)?